# Display other table data from drop down list when edit

Tags: php, laravel

Is that possible to get data from other table?

Let say in create table, I get all the info from genre table and display all data in drop down list

```
      <select name="mov_genre" id="mov_genre" class="form-control input-sm">
          <option value="">类型</option>
               @foreach(App\Genre::all() as $gData)
          <option value="{{$gData->gen_title}}">{{$gData->gen_title}}</option>
               @endforeach
      </select>
```

In edit page, I want to display it as well but how to display it as the genre I selected when create?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use `$gData->id` as `value` of each option. Because normally you store the `id` as foreign key and not something like the title.

But to your question itself: You can simply add an `if` statement that checks within the `foreach` loop if the current item is the selected one. In my example I assume you have a variable `$movie` which is the entry you want to edit.

```
  <select name="mov_genre" id="mov_genre" class="form-control input-sm">
      <option value="">-- SELECT GENRE --</option>
      @foreach(App\Genre::pluck('gen_title', 'id') as $key => $value)
          <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ optional($movie)->genre_id === $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $value }}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
```

Please note that I swapped `App\Genre::all()` for `App\Genre::pluck('gen_title', 'id')`. This will only load the both fields `gen_title` and `id` and put them in an array where `id` is the key and `gen_title` the value. It is done for better performance as we do not load unnecessary data.

Also note that `optional($movie)` will return `null` when `$movie` is not set. This is done to reduce weird `if` statements and is common practice.

Comment: I tried it but only show '-- SELECT GENRE --' . I wonder which part I missing.

Comment: Well, is there an `id` column on your `Genre` model? And what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Could be that `pluck()` was introduced later on the query builder. Try `App\Genre::all('id', 'gen_title')->pluck('gen_title', 'id')` instead.

Comment: I think the problem is not on the pluck. But it does not make the selection as I choose when I add the item. Let say Genre type I choose is 'Horror' , so it should be display 'horror' as well.